# 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/full-dotnet/new-db step by step

but I cannot add the "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore " namespace to Model.cs

I use Visual studio 2017

and install  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer(1.1.2) ,

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (1.1.1) ,

and .NET Framework 4.5.2

Visual Studio says:

The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

They added to .csproj :

[image]

Comment: Fx 4.5.2 shouldn't be in that list. Make sure you started with a .NET Core project and add the EF Core package with nuGet.

Comment: @HenkHolterman EF Core doesn't require .NET Core. It's possible that .NET 4.5.2 is a problem, but in that case, upgrading to .NET 4.6 *should* be enough.

Comment: @hvd - you're right, I missed that. And the package says "Fx = 4.5.1"

Comment: Thanks guys,I upgrade it to .Net Framework 4.6.2 ,but again I have this problem

Comment: You have to expand on "intall". Did you add packages with NuGet? What did the output window say? what can be seen when you expand "References" ?

Comment: Do try restarting VS2017.  Even now, in July 2017, this code doesn't seem particularly stable, and restarting VS did get rid of some of these errors for me...

Answer (score 0):

Copying the following code into the TodoApi.csproj from https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/first-web-api/sample/TodoApi worked for me on a similar issue.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Microsoft.AspNetCore.All may be excessive but it includes EntityFrameworkCore etc

Answer (score -2):

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.Shared.targets(90,5): Error: The Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package is not supported when targeting .NET Core 3.0 or higher.  A FrameworkReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App should be used instead, and will be implicitly included by Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.

For anyone at 3.0 or higher with same error

Comment: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.Shared.targets(111,5): Error: A PackageReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is not necessary when targeting .NET Core 3.0 or higher. If Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web is used, the shared framework will be referenced automatically. Otherwise, the PackageReference should be replaced with a FrameworkReference.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31908690)